# tkinter option menu wont set title

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, optionmenu

I cant get my option menu to display a title, I've done this in other programs and it worked fine. I even copied working code to this project and here it doesnt work. Is there something I'm missing?

The window is executed by calling it by the press of a button

```
def agregarEquipo(event=None):
    window = tk.Tk()
    wTitle = 'Example title'
    window.title(wTitle)
    window.configure(bg=bgColor_1)
    window.geometry('%dx%d' % (windX, windY))

    # The option menu
    listaEquipos = ['Equipos'] 
    menuEquipoText = tk.StringVar()
    menuEquipoText.set(listaEquipos[0])
    menuEquipo = tk.OptionMenu(window,menuEquipoText,*'Hello')
    menuEquipo.grid(row=0, column=0)

    window.mainloop()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hum. This is working for me. What OS/Python version you using?

Comment: I got it to work, thanks anyways. I'm using python3.7 btw

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by adding the parent widget as an argument to the tk.StringVar() statement.

Changed this:

```
 menuEquipoText = tk.StringVar()
```

To this:

```
 menuEquipoText = tk.StringVar(window)
```

And it all works fine now.
Anyways, could someone explain to me why this happens? I didn't need to this before

Comment: You dont happen to have 2 instances of Tk in your original code do you?

Comment: I think yes, actually "window" is set as `window=tk.TK()` inside a function that gets called by the press of a button in the `root` Tk widget.
Is that wrong?

Comment: Yes that would cause problems. If you have 2 `Tk()` Then you will end up with issues like this. Any tkinter method like `StringVar()` if not root window is given will automatically look for the 1st instance of the root window. So what ends up happening is it is being associated with that instance and not the 2nd instance. By adding `window` here you make it part of this instance so it works. That is if you do actually have `Tk()` in there twice.